# Store pem files on Heroku

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, heroku, pem

How do I securely store *.pem files on Heroku?

I'm using PHP mysqli to connect to an external MySQL server via SSL.

Something like this work fine. but requires me to upload the pem files in to my web root.

```
mysqli_ssl_set( $obj,
                '/mysql-ssl-certs/server-key.pem',
                '/mysql-ssl-certs/server-cert.pem',
                '/mysql-ssl-certs/ca-cert.pem',
                NULL,
                NULL);
```

My first through was Heroku environment variables, but seems like **mysqli_ssl_set** does not accept variables, only files.

So at the moment I have upload the files to a folder and protected the folder with **.htaccess**, I don't consider that safe and there must be a better solution.

Can the pem files be stored outside the webroot on Heroku, so they are not accessible from the internet.